# Ansible: recall other hosts values filtered by attribute

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I have the following *inventory* structure:

```yaml
cluster:
  server01.domain.com:
    host_id: 1 
    host_role: master
  server02.domain.com:
    host_id: 2
    host_role: follower
  server03.domain.com:
    host_id: 3
    host_role: follower
```

I need to implement a *task*, running only for servers 2 and 3, in which I should be able to see *server01* name.

I've tried

```yaml
  - name: my test task
      debug: "the fqdn of the server is: {{ vars['play_hosts'][0] }}"
    when: host_role == 'follower'
```

But the order I've used within my inventory is not respected.

Is there a way to call my cluster element when its host_role is equal to master?

Otherwise, it would be feasible to set *"global variable"* a can use for each host.

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      master_fqdn: {{ inventory_hostname }}
    when: host_role == 'master'
```

Unfortunately, this solution will create the master_fqdn variable only available for the first host.

**UPDATE**

The `order:inventory` option could be a solution but, as I said, it is not respected in my playbook. I don't know why but printing `{{ vars['play_hosts'] }}` doesn't report the inventory order.

Anyway, what I exactly need is the possibility to retrieve my first server name within a task running on other hosts just filtering the whole `play_hosts` array according to the `host_role` property value.
In other words:

- the task should run `when host_role == 'worker'`
- I should access to `vars['play_hosts'].key()` **IF** `host_role == 'master'`

Considering the possibility to declare a global variable like master_fqdn acceptable I've tried to

```
set_fact: 
  master_fqdn: {{ inventory_hostname }} 
when: host_role == 'master'
```

But unfortunately, this is only available for my first host.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the `hosts` variable as a `list`, and `slice` it to select just the last two hosts.

For example: suppose you have the following inventory:

```yaml
[cluster]
server01 ansible_host=127.0.0.1 host_id=1 host_role=master
server02 ansible_host=127.0.0.1 host_id=2 host_role=worker
server03 ansible_host=127.0.0.1 host_id=3 host_role=worker
```

You would write a `playbook` using the following `slice`:

```yaml
- hosts: cluster[1:2]
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: groups.cluster[0]
```

The output will look like this:

```yaml
❯ ansible-playbook playbooks/limit.yml

PLAY [cluster[1:2]] ************************************************************
Tuesday 01 June 2021  11:49:23 -0300 (0:00:00.020)       0:00:00.020 ********** 

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [server02] => 
  groups.cluster[0]: server01
ok: [server03] => 
  groups.cluster[0]: server01
```

---

### Edit

You can control the `playbook` execution by modifying the:

- `order`: Sets the order from which Ansible should pick the hosts.
- `serial`: Sets the batch size of the run.
- `throttle`: Restrict execution of time or CPU-intensive tasks.
- `strategy`: Controls Ansible task execution behavior.
- `run_once`: Runs the tasks on a single host and applies the results to all.

Here is an excerpt from [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#id4) that summaries their uses:

> You can set a number, a percentage, or a list of numbers of hosts you want to manage at a time with `serial`. Ansible completes the play on the specified number or percentage of hosts before starting the next batch of hosts. You can restrict the number of workers allotted to a block or task with `throttle`. You can control how Ansible selects the next host in a group to execute against with `order`. You can run a task on a single host with `run_once`. These keywords are not strategies. They are directives or options applied to a play, block, or task.

You mentioned that the order of the inventory is not respected. That is not true. Ansible, by default, will use the order of the inventory. The issue is that Ansible will also run the tasks in parallel, and the completion of the tasks will vary on each run.

Besides all these options, you can also use the `when` option to tell Ansible that it should skip running that task if the condition is not met. If you don't want to write `when` on multiple `tasks`, you can combine it with the `import_tasks` option. For example:

```yaml
- hosts: cluster
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  order: inventory
  strategy: linear
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - import_tasks: ../tasks/when.yml
      when: host_role == "worker"
```

And here is the output:

```yaml
❯ ansible-playbook playbooks/limit_2.yml

PLAY [cluster] *****************************************************************
Wednesday 02 June 2021  11:39:41 -0300 (0:00:00.019)       0:00:00.019 ******** 

PLAY [cluster] *****************************************************************
Wednesday 02 June 2021  11:39:41 -0300 (0:00:00.061)       0:00:00.081 ******** 

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [server02] => 
  groups.cluster[0]: server01

PLAY [cluster] *****************************************************************
Wednesday 02 June 2021  11:39:41 -0300 (0:00:00.061)       0:00:00.142 ******** 
ok: [server03] => 
  groups.cluster[0]: server01

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
server01                   : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server02                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server03                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

You can see that Ansible skipped the tasks on `server01`. I also configured some of the options previously mentioned to show how to use them.

Comment: I'm not sure I've fully understood your suggestion.
I need all three hosts in my playbook.
Only a single task has to be run on two hosts (with the hosrt_role == 'follower').
But I have to be able to use the name of the first host within this task.

I've also tried somthing like:

- name: debug message
  debug: 
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ cluster | selectattr('host_id', 'match', '1') | list }}"

but received the following error: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'host_id'

Comment: I've updated my examples to show how you can reference another `hosts` name. The `groups` variable is a dictionary with every `host` in your inventory. So, my recommendation would be for you to create a new `play` that would only be run on the last two servers and use the `groups` variable to access the variables of `server01`.

Comment: Therefore it is not possible nether to loop through a set of hosts excluding some of them matching some attributes values or create a global value with set_fact task?

Comment: Please see the last edit to check if your question was answered.

Comment: I've tried with your order option suggestion but it doesn't work. I've updated my question.